# has_one/has_many rails association with alternate source ID other then primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 3 models.

Model A belongs to model B and model B has many model C

by using `through` I can set in model A class `has_many :c,through: :b`

Now whenever I call `a_instance.cs` It would JOIN with table B unnecessarily What I want is direct association of `A` & `C` using `b_id` in both A & C class.

So how can I write a has_one/has_many rails association without `through` clause when both Source and Destination entities has same foreign_key of 3rd entity?  (`b_id` for this example)

```
class C
  belongs_to :b #b_id column is there in DB
end

class B
  has_many :cs
end

class A
  belongs_to :b #b_id column is there in DB
  has_many :cs , through: :b #This is the association in Question

  #WHAT I WANT TO DO. So something in place of primary_key which would fetch C class directly.
  has_many :cs ,class_name: 'C',foreign_key: 'b_id',primary_key: 'b_id'
end
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as `ruby-on-rails-4` *and* `ruby-on-rails-5`? The solution probably doesn't make a difference in this case, but it's advisable to actually specify the version you're using.

Comment: The last `has_many` with `foreign_key` and `primary_key` works for me, what issues are you having? Specifying `class_name` is not necessary, tested with Rails 5.1.4.

Comment: Agree, the last `has_many` works for me and also works w/o the `primary_key`.

Answer (score 1):

An example, Teacher and Student models belong to Group, Teacher has many Student:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :teachers
  has_many :students
end

class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :students, :foreign_key => 'group_id', :primary_key => 'group_id'
end

class Student < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
end
```

And you can retrieve a teacher's students in a group like this:

```
teacher = Teacher.find(:teacher_id)
students = teacher.students
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your example of classes A,B & C and changing only the implementation of class A.

```
class A
  belongs_to :b

  def cs
    self.id = b_id
    b_cast = self.becomes(B)
    b_cast.cs
  end
end
```

Console

```
A.first                    ==>#<A id: 105, b_id: 1 ...>
B.first                    ==>#<B id: 1 ...>
C.all                      ==>#<C id: 1, b_id: 1 ...>, 
                              #<C id: 2, b_id: 1 ...>, 
                              #<C id: 3, b_id: 1 ...>, 
                              #<C id: 4, b_id: 1 ...>



A.first.cs
A Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "as".* FROM "as" ORDER BY "as"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
C Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "cs".* FROM "cs" WHERE "cs"."b_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["b_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]                 

A.first.cs                 ==>#<C id: 1, b_id: 1 ...>, 
                              #<C id: 2, b_id: 1 ...>, 
                              #<C id: 3, b_id: 1 ...>, 
                              #<C id: 4, b_id: 1 ...>
```

Official #becomes(klass) documentation can be found 
[here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes)!

On other end, the same effect can be achieved creating an instance of the class B and giving it the id stored in A.first.b_id as follows:

```
B.new(id: A.first.b_id).cs
A Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "as".* FROM "as" ORDER BY "as"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
C Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "cs".* FROM "cs" WHERE "cs"."b_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["b_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]                 

B.new(id: A.first.b_id).cs ==>#<C id: 1, b_id: 1 ...>, 
                              #<C id: 2, b_id: 1 ...>, 
                              #<C id: 3, b_id: 1 ...>, 
                              #<C id: 4, b_id: 1 ...>
```

Comment: If the solution is necessarily through active records relation point it out so I may remove this answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But Solution regarding AR Association is required. Method base approach can be done in multiple ways but it removes all the flexibility which AR associations provide